# Logic is incorrect for the program in loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, struct, equals

So I'm trying to find the lowest year in pat.txt and highest year in don.txt:

Pat.txt

```
Androf O kidney 24 2012
Blaren B kidney 35 2010
Cosmer A kidney 35 2000
Eralod O heart 53 2009
Forend B kidney 31 2003
```

Don.txt

```
Zerk B kidney 20 2009
Rampe A kidney 31 2005
Darech B kidney 34 2008
Seo A kidney 26 2010
Yuio B kidney 26 2013
```

Code is as follows:

```
    struct Person {

    string surname;
    string BType;
    string organ;
    int age;
    int year, ID, IDp;
} Patient[50], Donor[50];
```

Then code of interest:

```
int Date = 5000;
        int Datel = 1000;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i ++){
                    for (i1 = 0; i1 < 6; i1++){

                            if ((Patient[i].BType == Donor[i1].BType) && (Patient[i].organ == Donor[i1].organ)){

                                    if (Patient[i].year < Date){
                                        Date = Patient[i].year;

                                    //}
                                        if ((Patient[i].year == Date ) && (Donor[i1].year > Datel)){
                                            Date = Patient[i].year;
                                            Datel = Donor[i1].year;
                                            cout << Date << "   " << Datel << "\n";

                                        }

                                    }
                            }
                        }
                }
```

I feel like the logic is incorrect in one of the if statements that is doing the equality. At the moment it is finding the highest patient and lowest doner. I have to flip them. Spent hours trying to figure this out, i would really appreciate it if someone can see my mistake. I'm sure its a silly little mistake, but for the life of me I just cant find it.

Comment: So you want it to print 2000 and 2013?

Comment: @Borys: You wrote "I'm trying to find the lowest year in pat.txt and highest year in don.txt" If so then why do you compare years from pat and don?

Comment: I want it to print out (for this particular case) 2003 for pat and 2013 for don as those two satisfy the if statement for having the same BType (B) and same organ. Otherwise its incorrect